# is there a way I can set waypoints?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a waypoint to my house so I can go back easily when I finish exploring the world and fighting mobs. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I would suggest using [`VoxelMap`](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/225179-voxelmap).

From [a post from the developer on the Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2261180-voxelmap-1-8-a-minimap-and-worldmap):

> To install:
>
> 1. install Liteloader. Follow the instructions in its thread. For 1.8, from the liteloader thread: "Development builds are available from the
>      [Jenkins build server](http://jenkins.liteloader.com/job/LiteLoaderInstaller/)". There's a beta build of Liteloader for 1.8
>      there
> 2. put the voxelmap .litemod file in your minecraft /mods folder
> 3. launch Minecraft with the liteloader profile

Answer (score 0):

beacons are a great way to waypoint an area in the world they can cost a lot of iron, gold, diamonds or emeralds but believe me it really helps. Another way is remembering the "X,Y and Z" location on your map i.e. X 233, Y 56, Z 12

Answer (score 0):

If you have a waypoint mod look in the controls for the hotkey. Once you find it leave controls and press the hotkey then you can set a waypoint. If you don't have any waypoint mods you can pillar up with any block and at the top place a torch. make sure you have a water bucket to slow your fall.

Comment: By the way this is pretty cheap and beacons work just as well.